# Построение графика на php

Tags: php

Кто сталкивался, посоветуйте, где можно посмотреть полноценные примеры реализации! Желательно буржуйские сайты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pChart - a PHP class to build charts](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) - вот, неплохая штука.

Comment: Ссылка не работает, чё делать будем?

Comment: @Mr.Black ссылка работает.

Answer (score 1):

Можно генерировать на PHP по базе данных и строить с помощью [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html).